# optimizacion de consulta en mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una base de datos con dos tablas.

- tabla 1: "users" que contiene mas de 4500 registros.
- tabla2: "payment" que contiene mas de 60.000 registros.

Breve demostración de la db

**tabla "users"**

| id | email |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | email1 |
| 02 | email2 |
| 03 | email 3 |

...etc

**tabla payment:**

| id_user | fecha_pay |
| --- | --- |
| 02 | 2022-04-16 14:32:57 |
| 02 | 2022-05-19 16:57:57 |
| 03 | 2022-02-22 10:12:57 |
| 01 | 2022-03-04 04:45:57 |
| 02 | 2022-04-10 23:01:57 |
| 01 | 2022-05-06 12:02:57 |

...etc

El objetivo es obtener la fecha del último registro de pago ( ultimo registro en payment)... de cada usuario registrado (users).

Esta es la consulta actual.

```
$sql = "SELECT u.id, u.email, p.id_user, p.fecha_pay 
FROM users u JOIN payment p ON u.id = p.id_user
WHERE p.fecha_pay = (SELECT max(fecha_pay) FROM payment p WHERE p.id_user = u.id)"
```

la consulta funciona (para una base de datos con menos registros), pero para la base de datos en donde necesito aplicarla se demora demasiado y se cancela la consulta.

**ACTUALIZACION**
Estructura de las tablas.

users
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

payment
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: le faltaran indices?

Comment: @gbianchi mm no estoy segura. Puedo añadir que puede que existan por lo menos 1 registro de pago con un id de usuario especifico, donde se haya eliminado ese id de usuario de users.

Comment: vas a tener que hacer un explain plan a la query en la base de datos real y tambien un profiling a ver donde se traba

Comment: @Lilibeth ¿podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agrega la definición de la estructura de ambas tablas junto con los índices y/o claves que tengan?

Comment: @Marcos en la tabla users el -id- tiene su indice , en la tabla payment su indice lo tiene en el -id_pay- (que no he agregado en el ejemplo de esta publicacion). Por otro lado, - id_user- no tiene ni indice, ni clave

Comment: El campo `id_user` de la tabla `payment` debería ser del mismo tipo y colación que el `id` de la tabla `users`. Además si crearas un índice sobre `id_user` debería ayudar a que el join sea más  rápido.

Comment: @Marcos entiendo. Y modificar el índice sobre id_user podría traer algún problema? Porque existen otras consultas sobre estas mismas tablas.

Comment: Depende, por ejemplo, si en otras tablas es un `TINYINT` y en la tabla `users` es un `INT`... digamos que eventualmente en las otras tablas los usuarios con `id` mayores a `255` no van a entrar y si el motor de la DB no esta configurado para tirar error, ahí si vas a tener un problema grave.

Comment: @Lilibeth, proba hacerlo [de esta forma](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c2SaGLaGiCi2BeWxMYxFXe/1) y contanos como resulto.

Comment: @Marcos listo, eso lo ha resuelto. Si quieres una valoración puedes publicar tu respuesta. Muy agradecida. Me instruiré mas sobre esto!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que solo necesitas obtener `fecha_pay` de la tabla `payment`, podrías hacerlo así:

```sql
SELECT 
    u.id,
    u.email,
    MAX(p.fecha_pay) as fecha_pay
FROM users u 
    JOIN payment p 
        ON u.id = p.id_user
GROUP BY u.id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c2SaGLaGiCi2BeWxMYxFXe/1)</kbd>

Comment: muchas gracias Marcos.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema debe ser la subconsulta, pero se me ocurre que en ves de hacer la consulta a la tabla users, ¿no será mejor, hacer la consulta a la tabla payment y luego con un Join traer los datos del usuario quedando algo como esto?:

```sql
SELECT
    max(fecha_pay),
    u.id,
    u.email,
    p.id_user,
    p.fecha_pay
FROM
    payment p
LEFT JOIN users u ON
    u.id = p.id_user
```

Comment: esto me regresa el pago de un solo usuario, necesito que me regrese el ultimo pago de *todos* los usuarios

Comment: por supuesto, hay que completarla, es una idea, usar la tabla payment en vez de la tabla users en el Where habría que ver como lo resolvemos si a través de un Group by o ver de que primary key disponemos si tuviéramos la estructura de ambas tablas creo que podríamos hacer más.

Comment: buen dia, acabo de actualizar la estructura de las tablas